# My program is not working properly and showing lots of error

Tags: python-3.x

I don't know how this code will work if any of you know how then please help

## Can you tell me what is the error in this code and how can I fix it

```
import pymysql

# Connecting to the database
def the():
    return pymysql.connect(host='localhost',database='project1',
                           user='root',password='Chitransh@994',
                           port=3306)

# Inserting to the database
def Table():
    conn = the()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "Create Table vehicle(modelno int primary key auto_increment, name VARCHAR(50)," \
            "owner name VARCHAR(50), MRP int)"
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
    print("Table created")
    conn.close()
Table()
```

## Error it is showing is

```
     File "C:\Users\MY DESK\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 29, in <module>
        Table()
      File "C:\Users\MY DESK\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 23, in Table
        cursor.execute(query)
      File "C:\Users\MY DESK\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line       148, in execute
        result = self._query(query)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\MY DESK\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line    310, in _query
        conn.query(q)
      File "C:\Users\MY DESK\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line   548, in query
        self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\MY DESK\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",  line 775, in _read_query_result
        result.read()
      File "C:\Users\MY DESK\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",  line 1156, in read
        first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\MY DESK\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
        packet.raise_for_error()
      File "C:\Users\MY DESK\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
        err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
      File "C:\Users\MY DESK\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line   143, in raise_mysql_exception
        raise errorclass(errno, errval)
    pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'name VARCHAR(50), MRP int)' at l     ine 1")
```

Comment: The error says: "You have an error in your SQL syntax". So you need to fix your SQL query.

Answer (score -1):

i think that you miss the semicolon in the sql query, and check did you install the mysql connector in your system

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I recommend giving whitespace the utmost attention to detail. Then, format your query in a consistent manner for readability.

Your query has an extra space in the middle.

```sql
// yours 
owner name VARCHAR(50),

// should be
owner_name VARCHAR(50),
```

So try this query instead, with formatted spacing and letter case:

```py
query = "CREATE TABLE vehicle (modelno INT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(50), owner_name VARCHAR(50), mrp INT, PRIMARY KEY (modelno))"
```

or in sql format with highlighting:

```sql
CREATE TABLE vehicle (
    modelno INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    owner_name VARCHAR(50),
    mrp INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (modelno)
)
```

Comment: Please give me an Upvote if you've found this helpful. It'll help me greatly in return so I can help others :)

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Comment: Thanks for your concerns it has a typing issue actually the typing style was changed since the typing style i saw in the viedo tutorial was different i also wrote it wrong. My issue is fixed thank you

Comment: Thanks for giving your precious time my code is now working in the correct manner